# What browser & version is targeted by preceding underscores in property names?

Tags: css

```
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 220px;
  _width: 160px;
```

I know it's some version of IE, 6, 7 or 8. But can't figure out which one...

Comment: Its for IE6 ([IE 6 Hack](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2008/05/07/ie6-underscore-hack.aspx))

Comment: why you dont try yourself and find which version of IE?

Comment: i think you can use expression web SuperPreview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSIE 5+ will process the tag as if there were no underscore, whereas other browsers will ignore that tag completely.

See http://wellstyled.com/css-underscore-hack.html

Comment: That page is really old - "MSIE 5+ will process the tag as if there were no underscore" implies that IE7/8/9 all have the same bug, but `_property` was fixed in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like IE6. As far as I remember, IE7 added support for min- and max-width.

Of course this solution makes it static for IE5+6, and dynamic for other browsers.